# Magento API for mobile app

Tags: magento, xml-rpc

We are trying to to develop a mobile app for an eCommerce site developed with magento. I am trying to use magento api. But the problem is i have to use apiuser & apikey to use the api.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
```

So i was wondering is there any other way to use the api & build my mobile app. Because it is not possible to build app for each individual user.

Answer (score 1):

You will use the same API User & API key for all your app users. The apiuser & apikey does not represent the logged in user (customer) of your store, but its merely the authentication details for accessing the Magento Soap endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Dayson is right, you have to use the same API key for all your users.

We've been working a lot on this kind of apps and we have just open sourced an SDK for Android and iOS to ease the connection with the Magento's APIs. Maybe it helps you with the rest of your development: http://meets.io